# Problem cxml PunchoutSetupRequest in Struts2... while receiving request

Tags: struts2, cxml-commercexml

I am using servlet to receive request in Struts2 for cXML punchout module, the XML document will be sent with request in stream and I had used `request.getInputStream()` and `request.getReader()` to receive but when the request hits my servlet from remote client system `inputSteram.read()` returns -1 , but `req.getContentLength()` returns length of the XML string from request object.

How can I get over from this issue? Is there any other way to carry out this process?

**note:** *the same servlet works in non-struts environment.......!*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved : If you are using inputStream in srvlet to read value stream, you are not suppose to use Request.getParameter().... before getting Stream value to InputStream through req.getInputStream()...

Ex:

Correct-- method

```
InputStream in=req.getInputStream();
  StringBuffer xmlStr=new StringBuffer();
    int d;
    while((d=in.read()) != -1){
              xmlStr.append((char)d);
    }
    System.out.println("xmlStr1--"+xmlStr.toString());
```

Below method will cause ISSUE:

```
String str = req.getParameter("SOMETEXT");

InputStream in=req.getInputStream();
  StringBuffer xmlStr=new StringBuffer();
    int d;
    while((d=in.read()) != -1){
              xmlStr.append((char)d);
    }
    System.out.println("xmlStr1--"+xmlStr.toString());
```